# Test that a value is correctly set before calling an asynchronous service in a component

Tags: testing, angular, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for an Angular2 app in which a component is calling an asynchronous service when it is initialized in order to load its data. Before loading data, it should set a `loading` flag to `true` in order to show a spinner, and then the `loading` flag is set back to `false`once the data has been retrieved.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.reloadEmployees(this.filter);
}

reloadEmployees(filter: string) {
  this.loading = true;
  this.employeeService.getEmployees(filter).subscribe((results: Employee[]) => {
    this.employees = results;
    this.loading = false;
  });
}
```

Here is how I wrote my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [EmployeeComponent],
    imports: [FormsModule, SpinnerModule, ModalModule, TranslateModule.forRoot()],
    providers: [
      { provide: EmployeeService, useValue: employeeServiceStub },
    ]
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmployeeComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  let employeeService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(EmployeeService);
  spy = spyOn(employeeService, 'getEmployees').and.returnValue(Observable.of(testEmployees));
});

it('should start loading employees when the component is initialized', fakeAsync(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.loading).toEqual(true);
}));
```

I was expecting the callback from the service to be run only if I call `tick()` in my test but apparently it is called anyway because `component.loading`is already back to `false` when I check its value. Note that if I comment out the line that sets `loading` back to false in the callback of the component, the test passes.

Any idea how I should test that?

Comment: Tried putting expect(component.loading).toEqual(true) before fixture.detectChanges()?  Just a thought. I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: But since reloadEmployees() is called in ngOnInit, and it is detectChanges that triggers ngOnInit, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rx.Observable.of` seems to be synchronous ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/752)). That's why `fakeAsync` wrapper doesn't work with it.

Instead you can use e.g. `Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(...))`.

In your case:

```
spy = spyOn(employeeService, 'getEmployees').and.returnValue(
  Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(testEmployees)));
```

Alternatively you can use [`async` scheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/schedulers/scheduler.md#scheduler-class-properties):

```
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Rx';
...
spy = spyOn(employeeService, 'getEmployees').and.returnValue(
  Observable.of(testEmployees, Scheduler.async));
```

I have prepared a working test sample on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nm9KJBA4PcsQvxmkmCTB?p=preview)

Comment: That looks promising (pun intended) but incredibly hacky, all the more so as my IntelliJ doesn't find where to import Promise from. Isn't there a way to make `Observable.of()` asynchronous by using the scheduler argument to it? (still reading through rxjs doc but couldn't find anything so far)